# Jquery ui autocomplete search label, value or other field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
<script>
    $(function() {
                    var products = [{"label":"Biscuit","value":532,"product_code":532,"product_name":"Biscuit","mrp":"25.00","selling_price":"22.00","measuring_type":"Qty","group_name":"TAX"},{"label":"Bread","value":533,"product_code":533,"product_name":"Bread","mrp":"23.00","selling_price":"21.00","measuring_type":"Qty","group_name":"NON TAXABLE"}];

        $( "#product_code" ).autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            source: products,
            minLength: 0,
            focus: function(event, ui){
                $('#product_name').val(ui.item.product_name);
                $('#mrp').val(ui.item.mrp);
                $('#selling_price').val(ui.item.selling_price);
                $('#measuring_type').val(ui.item.measuring_type);
                $('.measuring_type').text(ui.item.measuring_type);
                $('#group_name').val(ui.item.group_name);
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#product_code').val(ui.item.product_code);
                $('#product_name').val(ui.item.product_name);
                $('#mrp').val(ui.item.mrp);
                $('#selling_price').val(ui.item.selling_price);
                $('#measuring_type').val(ui.item.measuring_type);
                $('.measuring_type').text(ui.item.measuring_type);
                $('#group_name').val(ui.item.group_name);
                $('#quantity').focus();
            }
        }).focus(function(){
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });

        $("#product_code").autocomplete().data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem =  function( ul, item )
        {
            return $( "<li>" )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + " - " + item.selling_price + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
        };

    });
</script>
```

The above code shows "all label" fields when i focus on to an autocomplete input, And i am typing something so it filters that label. Fine till now.

I want the typed text not only search and return label alone, i want it to search the matching text in value, or mrp or selling price ("mrp":"25.00","selling_price":"22.00"), i had those thing in the source. how can i achieve it?

Comment: You can write additional information like selling price in attributes of DOM object and then search by it https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: im using jquery ui autocomplete, will it work?

Comment: here i have only one input box with so many values, how can i try it?

Comment: It's only looking at the `label` items. You could include the `mrp` in the results, but you can see in the example here, https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data it's only filtering/searching the `label`. You would have to write your own search function,

Comment: Or, you could make an autocomplete for each of the 6 fields?

Comment: Test Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6xgg4074/

Comment: Scratch my earlier comment, I forgot about the Request / Response feature. Creating something that might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return your `source` from a `fucntion(request, response)` like so: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6xgg4074/5/

```
function isInt(n) {
  return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
}

function isFloat(n) {
  return Number(n) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}

$(function() {
  var products = [{
    "label": "Cheese",
    "value": 531,
    "product_code": 531,
    "product_name": "Cheese",
    "mrp": "8.95",
    "selling_price": "6.95",
    "measuring_type": "Pnd",
    "group_name": "TAX"
  }, {
    "label": "Biscuit",
    "value": 532,
    "product_code": 532,
    "product_name": "Biscuit",
    "mrp": "25.00",
    "selling_price": "22.00",
    "measuring_type": "Qty",
    "group_name": "TAX"
  }, {
    "label": "Bread",
    "value": 533,
    "product_code": 533,
    "product_name": "Bread",
    "mrp": "23.00",
    "selling_price": "21.00",
    "measuring_type": "Qty",
    "group_name": "NON TAXABLE"
  }, {
    "label": "Cracker",
    "value": 534,
    "product_code": 534,
    "product_name": "Cracker",
    "mrp": "12.00",
    "selling_price": "7.00",
    "measuring_type": "Qty",
    "group_name": "TAX"
  }];

  $("#product_code").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      console.log(req);
      var results = [];
      if (isInt(parseInt(req.term)) || isFloat(parseFloat(req.term))) {
        // Number entered, check MRP or Selling Price
        console.log("Number found.");

        $.each(products, function(k, v) {
          var mrp = v.mrp.toString();
          var sell = v.selling_price.toString();
          if (mrp.startsWith(req.term) || sell.startsWith(req.term)) {
            results.push(products[k]);
          }
        });
      } else {
        //Text entered, check labels
        console.log("Text found.");
        $.each(products, function(k, v) {
          var label = v.label.toLowerCase();
          if (label.startsWith(req.term.toLowerCase())) {
            results.push(products[k]);
          }
        });
      }
      resp(results);
    },
    minLength: 0,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      $('#product_name').val(ui.item.product_name);
      $('#mrp').val(ui.item.mrp);
      $('#selling_price').val(ui.item.selling_price);
      $('#measuring_type').val(ui.item.measuring_type);
      //$('.measuring_type').text(ui.item.measuring_type);
      $('#group_name').val(ui.item.group_name);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#product_code').val(ui.item.product_code);
      $('#product_name').val(ui.item.product_name);
      $('#mrp').val(ui.item.mrp);
      $('#selling_price').val(ui.item.selling_price);
      $('#measuring_type').val(ui.item.measuring_type);
      //$('.measuring_type').text(ui.item.measuring_type);
      $('#group_name').val(ui.item.group_name);
      $('#quantity').focus();
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<a>" + item.label + " - $" + item.selling_price + "</a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  }
});
```

I added a few example items for testing different types of entries. To help identify a number or float, e.g. 21 or 21.00, I added a some small functions. To create the search, I used a function where the entry is passed to `req.term` and the callback function is `resp()`. Now we examine the entry and determine if the user has entered text or some type of number. We then find the products that match this and return them as a an array.

This is all based on the example from https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: perfect! ".autocomplete("instance")._renderItem" - is for may be older version,  removing it and adding the following code worked for me, $("#product_code").autocomplete().data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem =  function( ul, item )
        {
            return $( "<li>" )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + " - ₹" + item.selling_price + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
        };

Comment: @arun I just followed the example. Both appear to work to render the Items.